# OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter with more than 1000 qualified Opportunity record

Tags: apex, opportunity, territory-management, enterprise

As per the Salesforce documentation, the OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter class will take up to 1000 qualified Opportunity record to process.

But what will happen if the number of qualified Opportunity records
`(IsExcludedFromTerritory2Filter=false)` is more than 1000? Is it going to break into two different processes each handling max 1000 records?